# Starting tomcat6 shows missing conf directory.

Tags: apt, configuration, tomcat

I've just installed Tomcat6 via apt-get on lucid.

Looking at the directory created here:    `/usr/share/tomcat6`

I was expecting a `conf` directory to be created under this (based on experiences elsewhere).  Instead there was a `skel` directory created. Under this there was the directories `bin` and `conf`.

Do I need to patch up the installation by creating a hard link of a `conf` directory inside tomcat6 that points to `.../tomcat6/skel/conf` - or is there something better?

PS - Why do I need to to this? Why doesn't it work out the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/share` generally contains read-only data. You're likely looking for the `/var/lib/tomcat6/` directory which contains both the `conf` and `logs` directories.

`skel` is the abbreviation of "skeleton" which means it should be copied somewhere.

According to the [Ubuntu manual on tomcat](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/tomcat.html), you should create an instance with:

```
tomcat6-create-instance tomcat-instance
```

This will create a directory named "tomcat-instance" containing some subdirectories like `conf`. To start it, run:

```
tomcat-instance/bin/startup.sh
```

For more information and other links, please refer to the [Ubuntu manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/tomcat.html).